# How create a kudu table in cloudera quickstart VM

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-quickstart-vm, apache-kudu

I have been trying to create a kudu table in impala using the cloudera quickstart VM following this example 
https://kudu.apache.org/docs/quickstart.html

```
    CREATE TABLE sfmta
PRIMARY KEY (report_time, vehicle_tag)
PARTITION BY HASH(report_time) PARTITIONS 8
STORED AS KUDU
AS SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_time,  'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS report_time,
  vehicle_tag,
  longitude,
  latitude,
  speed,
  heading
FROM sfmta_raw;
```

getting the following error:

ERROR: AnalysisException: Table property 'kudu.master_addresses' is required when the impalad startup flag -kudu_master_hosts is not used. The VM used is cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.13.0-0-virtualbox. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> If the -kudu_master_hosts configuration property is not set, you can
>   still associate the appropriate value for each table by specifying a
>   TBLPROPERTIES('kudu.master_addresses') clause in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement or changing the TBLPROPERTIES('kudu.master_addresses') value
>   with an ALTER TABLE statement.

So your table creation should looks like

```
 CREATE TABLE sfmta
PRIMARY KEY (report_time, vehicle_tag)
PARTITION BY HASH(report_time) PARTITIONS 8
STORED AS KUDU
TBLPROPERTIES ('kudu.master_addresses'='localhost:7051') 
AS SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_time,  'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS report_time,
  vehicle_tag,
  longitude,
  latitude,
  speed,
  heading
FROM sfmta_raw;
```

7051 is the default port for kudu master.